# Verilog Include File Conditionally

Tags: file, include, verilog, system-verilog

Is there a way to include a file in Verilog based on parameter value? The following includes both the files because parameters are not evaluated until compile time, whereas pre-processor macros are evaluated before that. What's the best way to achieve this?

```
generate
  if (PARAM_A == 1) begin
    `include "file_a"
  end else begin
    `include "file_b"
  end
endgenerate
```

Comment: This seems like a classic case of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please explain what's in the two files, and how PARAM_A gets its value.

Comment: The file having this code is a common file used for implementation 2 different designs. It is done like this to avoid duplication as there is lot of commonality between the designs. PARAM_A tells me which design I am working with. `file_a` and `file_b` again have implementations slightly different based on design, and they include variables, logic and instances of other design, basically like any other module.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, `include` statements are compiled *before* `generate` statements. Therefore, in your example compilation will include both files. The rest will depend on the contents of the included file itself.

If the files contain definitions of text macros then all such definitions from both files will be included in the compilation process and will be visible after the inclusions.

If the files contain fragments of real code (e.g., always blocks, module instantiations), those will follow the rules of the generate block. In other works will be instantiated conditionally based on the value of the `PARAM_A`. So, despite the fact that both files are included, you will end up with correct conditional instantiation of the code parts.

In order to completely prevent inclusion of the files you need to use `ifdef/ifndef` constructs with text macros:

```
`ifdef MACRO_A
`include "file_a"
`else
`include "flie_b"
`endif
```

Comment: I like the case where conditionally I can include both files using the parameter case, but unfortunately the scope of all variable defined in the files changes, so I would have to reference them with a hierarchical name including generate label to use them outside. It seems I may have to create a separate module instead of calling the `include.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the two files A and B to select between different module instances. You can use a generate-`if` statement to select between two instances or you can use the `config` construct which allows you to compile a module with the same name into two different libraries, and then select which library you want to pull the definition from.

For synthesizable code in either case, you will need to pass any common signals through ports to these modules. If the code is not to be synthesizable, you can use a direct upwards reference without having to define a port

Comment: OK, thank you for the answer! I need synthesizable code, so I will have to create modules with ports. I was trying to reuse legacy code, which wasn't a module, but Verilog code.